# Como fazer uma unica requisição com ajax e jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, banco-de-dados, requisição

Tenho mais de 50 checkbox,quando clico nele, ele verificado o estado com jquery passo pro ajax trazer os dados da página "home.php", mas do jeito que está assim, tenho que duplicar o código e mudar o **id** dos checkbox pro ajax ir na página do select me trazer o retorno e ta deixando meu index enorme. 
Gostaria de uma solução, não sei muito de ajax, mas quero um unico codigo ajax que vai receber os valores checkados e fazer a requisição. Ao invés de duplicar os ajax e ir mudando os **id**.

Jquery e AJAX

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 $("#cartao").click(function(){
                         if($('#cartao').is(':checked')){
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "php/home_.php",  // coloque aqui o endereço que vai buscar os dados no banco         
                                success: function (data) {                                  
                                    $('#conteudo').html(data); 
                                    $('#conteudo').show(); // Mostrar o retorno em texto no html

                                      $.each(data, function (i, element) {
                                        $('#conteudo').html(element.linha_usuario); // ou assim
                                     });
                                }

                            });
                           }
                     });

            </script>
```

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 $("#consorcio").click(function(){
                         if($('#consorcio').is(':checked')){
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "php/select_conso.php",  // coloque aqui o endereço que vai buscar os dados no banco         
                                success: function (data) {                                  
                                    $('#conteudo_').html(data); 
                                    $('#conteudo_').show(); // Mostrar o retorno em texto no html

                                      $.each(data, function (i, element) {
                                        $('#conteudo').html(element.linha_usuario); // ou assim
                                     });
                                }

                            });
                           }
                     });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo visto você já sabe que um `id` deve ser único na página, tanto que está usando um `id` para cada checkbox. Até aí tudo bem. Porém utilizar vários id's numa mesma coleção de elementos não é a melhor utilização do atributo.

Como você não mostrou o HTML dos checkbox, há duas alternativas melhores a se fazer do que usar um id para cada elemento.

Se os checkbox estão todos numa mesma div, desta forma:

```
<div class="opcoes">
   <input type="checkbox" data-url="home_"> Cartão
   <input type="checkbox" data-url="select_conso"> Consórcio
</div>
```

Você pode selecioná-los da seguinte forma:

```
$(".opcoes :checkbox")
```

Veja que não foi preciso usar nenhuma id. Selecionei todos os checkbox que estão dentro da div `.opcoes`.

Coloquei um atributo `data-url` com o nome da página a ser requisitada (apenas o nome da página, sem o caminho completo e sem a extensão `.php`). O valor desse atributo você irá pegar no AJAX de acordo com o checkbox marcado:

```
$(".opcoes :checkbox").click(function(){
   if(this.checked){
      $.ajax({
         url: "php/" + this.dataset.url +".php",  // coloque aqui o endereço que vai buscar os dados no banco         
         success: function (data) {                                  
            $('#conteudo').html(data); 
            $('#conteudo').show(); // Mostrar o retorno em texto no html

            $.each(data, function (i, element) {
               $('#conteudo').html(element.linha_usuario); // ou assim
            });
         }
      });
   }
});
```

---

Agora, se os checkboxes estiverem "espalhados", ou seja, não possuem uma div pai em comum, você poderia colocar uma `class` em cada um deles, mantendo a mesma lógica do exemplo anterior, apenas mudando seletor do evento `click`:

Exemplo do HTML:

```
<input class="opcao" type="checkbox" data-url="home_"> Cartão
<input class="opcao" type="checkbox" data-url="select_conso"> Consórcio
```

jQuery:

```
$(":checkbox.opcao").click(function(){
   if(this.checked){
      $.ajax({
         url: "php/" + this.dataset.url +".php",  // coloque aqui o endereço que vai buscar os dados no banco         
         success: function (data) {                                  
            $('#conteudo').html(data); 
            $('#conteudo').show(); // Mostrar o retorno em texto no html

            $.each(data, function (i, element) {
               $('#conteudo').html(element.linha_usuario); // ou assim
            });
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: O ajax tem que vir na index? não posso ter esses arquivos em uma pasta chamada 'js' e chamar ela dentro como uma função e carregar junto com a página?

Comment: Pode como quiser. Pode criar um arquivo `.js` e carregar. Só é preciso ajustar o caminho dos aquivos .php no AJAX.

Comment: Não ta indo, quando clico não me traz retorno

Comment: vou por no github pra você ver

Comment: https://github.com/lauradevcode/bb_template botei tudo junto ai, pra olhar onde to errando

Comment: Tem um erro nesta linha: `url: "php/"home_ + this.dataset.url +".php",`... deveria ser `url: "php/"+ this.dataset.url +".php",` se os arquivos .php estiverem numa subpasta "php/"... se estiverem na mesma pasta deveria ser `url: this.dataset.url +".php",`

Comment: se eu quiser separar, quando mostra na div, ele carrega todos os registros 'cartão', mas quero que cada linha apareça em um flexbox, separado, como posso fazer isso? 
No caso quero que o registro da 1º linha apareça na primeira div, ai abro outra div fora e o 2º registro entra la e assim sucessivamente...

Comment: Aí já é outra questão e não tem como eu explicar por aqui. :/